# Adjusting basic football simulation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, probability

I need help with adjusting my very basic football matches simulation algorithm. It doesn't need to take in account anything other than team rating (combined rating of team players). I came up with something, but the results are not very interesting:
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVE9l.jpg)
i.e they almost always end up (zero) - (something)

Here's the algorithm

```
 double flagIncrementer = 0.10;
 while(!flag){ 
            if(new Random().nextDouble() <= baseChance - (homeTeamRating - awayTeamRating)){
                teamAwayScore++;
                boolean scoredFlag = false;
                while(!scoredFlag){ 
                    for(Player player : away.getPlayerList()){
                        if(new Random().nextDouble() <= player.getProbabilityWeight()){
                            awayScorers.add(player);
                            scoredFlag = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(new Random().nextDouble() <= baseChance - (awayTeamRating - homeTeamRating)){
                teamHomeScore++;
                boolean scoredFlag = false;
                while(!scoredFlag){
                    for(Player player : home.getPlayerList()){
                        if(new Random().nextDouble() <= player.getProbabilityWeight()){
                            homeScorers.add(player);
                            scoredFlag = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (new Random().nextDouble() <= flagIncrementer) {
                flag = true; 
            } else {
                flagIncrementer += 0.10; //inkrementiraj kako bi se izbjegla beskonačna petlja
            }

        }
```

It's very simple, I just generate a random number and then see if I get a number that is less than the base chance accounted for difference in team rating. I repeat that for second team. Loop can exit on the first iteration, but it doesn't have to be. If it doesn't, I increment my control variable so it has a higher chance to exit on the next iteration.

I'm not particularly adept at statistics nor math, but even directing me in the right way is very much appreciated.

Comment: Try multiplying your variables by different constants and seeing the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for soccer games, 0 is not uncommon, I don't see what's wrong with it.
But here is an alternative view:
1> determine total goals, which can poisson distribution.
2> For each of the goal, determine which team goaled, which can use the normlized team strength: A/(A+B) vs B/(A+B). I would suggest something benefit the stronger team more which seems to be more real world result.